# In java How Do I Take A Value From a Jbutton As It Is An Input From The Keyboard?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I have designed a gui that have many jbuttons like a calculator so that each button contains one number as a text but this buttons are used to insert values to different components like jtable , textfield ,etc, according to which component the user selects.
the question is can i take the values from those buttons as it came from keyboard(system.in)???

Comment: exactly what values do you want from a JButton?

Comment: i have 10 buttons having values from 0 to 9 as a text for example button0 have the value 0 button1 have the value 1 ....

Comment: What you want are KeyListeners. Simply press your jbuttons on key press, no need to do anything with system.in

Comment: Deltaris can you give more details please

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object of `JButton`, say:

```
JButton btn = new JButton();
```

Then you can use the `getText();` method to get the text of the button. So, if you have a button with text as "1" on it, it will return you "1".

```
String text = btn.getText();
```

If you want to implement ActionListener, try this:

```
btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textField.setText("1"); //if you simply want to set the value
            textField.setText(textField.getText()+"1"); //if you want to set the operator field in a calculator.
         }

      });
```

Comment: yes, i know that but i am asking if i can take it as it comes from the keyboard as(system.in)  to prevent using many conditions,
thanks

Comment: what property of (System.in) do you want to implement in your button?

Comment: first i select which component i need to edit the data in
then i take the data from the selected button
what i need is to put the data in the selected component as if i am inserting this data from the keyboard

Comment: So in the addActionListener of the button, you can simply put the data in the desired components. This should probably be the same as inserting data from the keyboard.

Comment: Priyank Gupta can you give more details please